# how to subtract a data from a table with another table where 1 table is same in both the id?

Tags: laravel-5.3

I have 2 tables one is issue and another is add. Both have a same field in database which is the `book_id`. I want to subtract in add while issuing in issue table. I have a `quantity(int)` field in add where the the total value of the quantity should be subtract with the number of time a id is issued in issue table.

```
            <!--controller-->
    $data = DB::table('library')
        ->join('issue','library.book_no','=','issue.book_no')
        ->select('issue.book_no','library.isbn_no','library.book_no','library.book_title','book_type','library.author_name','library.quantity','library.edition','library.price','library.publisher_name')
        ->get();
           return view('library.librarylist',['librarys'=>$data]);




                  @foreach($librarys as $library)
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{{route("admin.libraryissue", $library->id)}}">{{$library->book_no}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{$library->isbn_no}}</td>
                    <td>{{$library->book_title}}</td>
                    <td>{{$library->book_type}}</td>
                    <td>{{$library->author_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{$library->quantity}} |   </td>
                    <td>{{$library->edition}}</td>
                    <td>{{$library->price}}</td>
                    <td>{{$library->publisher_name}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs "><a href="{{route("admin.Editlibrary", $library->id)}}">Edit</a></button> | <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-detail open-modal" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delID">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching to decrease the quantity when Issuing the book from the issue controller, You can decrease the quantity in library table by :-

```
App\library::where('book_id',[Library_book_ID])
                    ->update(['quantity' => DB::raw('quantity-1')]);
```

And In quantity You can get the no of available Books from the quantity number.